# Are distributions all continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, distribution-theory

By a distribution, I mean it is a linear functional of the space of smooth compactly supported functions over $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n).$

I am reading a textbook by Strichartz, named A Guild to Distribution Theory and Fourier Transforms.

He wrote that *linear functionals all tend to be continuous*.

As we know, there are plenty of linear functionals which are not continuous. So what he referred to may be distributions. i.e. Distributions all tend to be continuous.

He gave a rough explanation which I think is not a proof.

**His explanation:**

Let $\varphi$ and $\varphi_1$ be in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n),$ and $f$ be a distribution.

And let $\varphi_2:=\varphi_1-\varphi$

Then $\varphi_1=\varphi+\varphi_2$

Move $\varphi_1$ closer to $\varphi$ by considering $\varphi+t\,\varphi_2$ and let $t$ get small.

Then $\langle f,\varphi+t\,\varphi_2\rangle=\langle f,\varphi\rangle+t\,\langle f,\varphi_2\rangle$ by linearity, and as $t$ gets small this gets close to $\langle f,\varphi\rangle.$

**End of explanation.**

I think, to prove the continuity of $f$, we need to show $\langle f,\varphi_1\rangle\to\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ when $\varphi_1 \to \varphi.$

While in the explanation, what he proved is that $\langle f,\varphi+t\,\varphi_2\rangle\to\langle f,\varphi\rangle$ when $t\to 0.$

He also wrote that *this does not constitute a proof of continuity, since the definition requires more "uniformly", but it should indicate that a certain amount of continuity is built into linearity.*

And, *all distribution you will ever encounter will be continuous.*

**So my problem is, are distributions all continuous?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the last italic phrase, it seems that continuity is not part of the definition of distribution..

Comment: @Berci Sure, we never require that a distribution is continuous in the definition. My problem is that, can we prove that all distributions are continuous?

Comment: No. It's a weaker property in the explanation, we could call it 'linear continuity' which is satisfied by linearity.

Comment: "A certain amount of continuity" - namely continuity along lines (or in any restriction to finite-dimensional subspaces)

Comment: Part of the definition of a distribution is:

$$\phi(f_n)\to\phi(f) \qquad \text{if }\|f_n-f\|\to0\text{ and }\|\partial_\alpha f_n- \partial_\alpha f\|\to0\text{ for all multi-indices $\alpha$}$$

It follows $\phi$ is continuous wrt the topology generated by the semi-norms $\|\partial_\alpha f\|=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R^d}|\partial_\alpha f|$. This is the usual topology for test-functions.

Comment: @s.harp OP is only assuming linearity in his definition of distribution. I wonder if this is also the definition that is used in the book (I actually have the book but I can't seem to find a rigorous definition of distribution in it - which pretty much represents why I personally dislike it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This claim would be equivalent to saying that all linear functionals on the topological vector space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are continuous.

This is not true, indeed, on any infinite dimensional topological vector space $X$ over a field $K$ there is a linear functional which is discontinuous.

Indeed, let $X$ be an infinite dimensional topological vector space, and let $\left\{e_n\right\}$ be a vanishing $(e_n\to 0)$ infinite sequence of linearly independent vectors on $X$, which may be easily constructed using continuity of the scalar product map. Define a linear functional $f$ on $X$ as any linear extension of the map
$$f(e_n):=n $$
Then the sequence $\left\{e_n\right\}\subset X$ is such that $e_n\to 0$, but $f(e_n)\not\to 0$.

For instance, in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ (but it is the same in higher dimensions), recall that we say that a sequence of test functions $\left\{\varphi_n\right\}$ converges to $0$ iff their supports $\operatorname{supp}\varphi_n$ are all contained on some compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi_n^{(k)}\to 0$ uniformly on $K$ for each order of differentiation $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

> **EDIT:** The above is the usual topology that is set in the space of test functions $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In order to discuss whether
>   a functional $f:C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous
>   we first need to fix a topology on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so I
>   assume you are referring to this one.

We may start from a function  $0\neq \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and then set
$$e_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}\varphi\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
so that the $\left\{e_n\right\}$ are linearly independent (since their supports are disjoint), $\operatorname{supp}e_n\subset \operatorname{supp}\varphi+[-1,0)$ and $e_n^{(k)}=\frac{1}{n}\varphi^{(k)}\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)\to 0$ uniformly for all $k$ as $n\to +\infty$. Thus, $\left\{e_n\right\}$ is a vanishing sequence of linearly independent vectors, and the functional $f$ defined above in the general case is a discontinuous linear functional on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

On the other hand, this is basically a sequence of bump functions which quickly reduces in overall size as $n\to +\infty$ and slowly shifts towards the left. Can you imagine a *reasonable* linear functional which blows up on such a sequence of functions?
As $n\to +\infty$, nothing meaningful 'blows up' here. I think this goes to show that you can usually expect your distributions to be continuous.